# How to select item from unordered list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, unordered

I have a function that fills my unordered list.

```
$("#DBSearch").append('<ul id="List" data-role="listview">');


for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{           
    $("#DBSearch").append("<li value=" + i + "><a href="+ "#" + ">" + obj.Search[i].Title + "</a></li>" );      
}
```

When I click on an item in the list I want my text box `strSearch` to fill with that item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click a `li` in list dbsearch it will replace the text with `strSearch`

```
$("#List").on("click", "li", function() {
    $("#strSearch").val($(this).text());
});
```

If you want to replace the text of the nested `a` link use `$("a", this).text(...)`.

Also a note, generally you shouldn't capitalize ids/classes in html

Update: here's a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RyG95/1)

Comment: I suppose OP needed `$('#strSearch').val(this.attr('value));`

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong. The function itself isn't being called when I click an item.

Comment: Probably because you're appending the list items to `dbsearch` and not `list` @MickB

Comment: @MickB see the fiddle

Comment: I tried your changes and now my list won't display. Do I need to close my ul tag at the end?

Comment: Ok I had a typo on my variable case. It is working now. Thank you very much.